# angular multiple components parent component control lost

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to Angular. I have a page(Page1) with 2 options menu on the top . When the first option is clicked Page1.html is displayed and when clicking the second menu  another component(Page2) is displayed  in the context area.
i was able to get the menu and the component 2 to be displayed. The issue is that when I am in page 2 , clicking the menu item again does not display me the page 1 .. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

```
Page1 . html

  <div fxFlex="none">
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="group1" >
      <mat-button-toggle value="Group1" >Group 1</mat-button-toggle>      
      <mat-button-toggle value="Group2" >Group 2</mat-button-toggle>
  </div>

//html for the page 1

<div *ngIf="group2" >  // i verify with a boolean if the group 2 is clicked
    
    <app-group2></app-group2>
  </div>

Page2.html

very simple html .
```

Clicking the menu items from any page should always present me  the corresponding context

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding some boolean checks.